# regex to ignore pattern if it has certain substring

Tags: regex

I have a large xml file.  A snip of it looks like this:

```
<data key="label">1</data><data key="user_id">1006.0</data><data key="pit_component_id">1</data><data key="customer_code">666.0</data><data key="user_id">666.0</data>
```

I am using regex to try and identify the key's associated with particular values but not with the key `customer_code`.

For example in the previous string I want to capture only the keys associated with the value `666`.  So I would want the `user_id` captured b/c it's associated with 666, but not `customer_id` or the other keys.

The closest to success that I have come is:

```
<data key="(?!customer_code).*">666.0<\/data>
```

It will ignore `customer_code` keys but also captures long sequences before those keys.  On my example it captures the whole sequence when what I want is just `<data key="user_id">666.0</data>`.  How can I capture just the pattern of interest?

Comment: Use an XML parser rather than processing XML with regexp.

Comment: Can you clarify? The content "666.0" is between both user_id and customer_code. Do you need the keys value associated with the content "666.0" that is _NOT_ customer_code ?

Comment: `.*` will skip over `>` to satisfy the condition and consume all the characters up to the last `">666.0</data>`. To stay inside `<`...`>` you need to replace `.*` with a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^>]*` making it [`<data key="(?!customer_code)[^>]*>666\.0<\/data>`](https://regex101.com/r/neJbKE/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

If regex is what you want, you'd probably use this. *Group 2* holds the keys value needed.
But an  xml parser is recommended in this case.

```
(?><data(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\skey\s*=\s*(['"])(?!customer_code)([\S\s]*?)\1(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)*?>)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>)\s*666\.0\s*</data\s*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/czWHEp/1

**(*Uses an atomic group, pcre/java*)**

```
 # Begin data tag
 
 (?>
      < data                 
      (?= \s )
      (?=                           # Asserttion 
                                         # Up to key Attribute
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s key \s* = \s* 
           
           ( ['"] )                      # (1), Quote
           (?! customer_code )           # Not customer code
           ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (2), key Value
           \1 
                                         # After key attribute
           (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )*?
           >
      )
      
      # Have the key value, just match the rest of tag
      
      \s+ 
      (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
      
      >                             # End data tag
 )
 \s* 666 \. 0 \s* 
 </ data \s*  >                # Must have 666.0 content (in an atomic way)
```

**(*Does not use an atomic group, Python/JS/C#/pcre/java*)**
*Group 3* holds the keys value needed.

```
(?=(<data(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\skey\s*=\s*(['"])(?!customer_code)([\S\s]*?)\2(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)*?>)\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>))\1\s*666\.0\s*</data\s*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/d3I1u6/1

```
 # Begin data tag
 
 (?=
      (                             # (1 start)
           < data                 
           (?= \s )
           (?=                           # Asserttion 
                                              # Up to key Attribute
                (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
                \s key \s* = \s* 
                
                ( ['"] )                      # (2), Quote
                (?! customer_code )           # Not customer code
                ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (3), key Value
                \2 
                                              # After key attribute
                (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )*?
                >
           )
           
           # Have the key value, just match the rest of tag
           
           \s+ 
           (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
           
           >                             # End data tag
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
 \1                            # Entire tag
 \s* 666 \. 0 \s* 
 </ data \s*  >                # Must have 666.0 content
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer!

Answer (score -1):

Does this regex101 solution work for you?

```
key="(?<key>.*)">(?=666)
```

See: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fiMKxo/1)

It will capture into a named capture group "key"